# Ng-bootstrap dynamically change #id in For loop

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I use ng-bootstrap in my Angular 4 application. I try to dynamically change #id in my ng-template tag in For loop, but unfortinally without success. If somebody has an idea I'll be very grateful. 
This my html file.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let page of clientsPagesData; let i = index;">
                          <td>
                            {{page.clientPage.title}}
                          </td>
                          <td [innerHTML]="page.clientPage.content">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <button (click) = "editPage('editContent'+i)" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit/View</button>
                            
                            <ng-template #editContent{{i}} let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">View/Edit page</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                Modal content
                                 
                              </div>
                            </ng-template>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
```

The problem is in this piece of code: ng-template #editContent{{i}}

Thank you again for your help :))

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You shouldn't have N times the same template for your modal. Create a single component for the content of your modal, and pass data to the component when displaying the modal, as shown in the "Components as content" demo in the documentation of ng-bootstrap.

Comment: Good idea, thank you :)